# How to save and email a whole scrollview on android?

Tags: android, scrollview

I need to save the scrollview and all of its contents and in turn email it. The main issue is saving the whole scrollview rather than just what appears on the screen. Is there a way to save a whole scrollview, and if so how?

It's in a LinearLayout inside the scrollView.
I'm trying to save a table, here is the method I'm using to save the table:

```
public void saveTable(){
    View v = findViewById(R.id.all_tables);
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    int height = ((ScrollView) v).getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    int width =((ScrollView) v).getChildAt(0).getWidth();
    v.layout(0, title.getMeasuredHeight(), width, height);
    v.buildDrawingCache();
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());


    try {
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CE_Budgets");
        if (!file.exists())
            file.mkdir();

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CE_Budgets/tables.png");
        if (!(file.exists())) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It didn't work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: explain what you are trying to save and post some code

Comment: Yea, explain what do you want ... and in what format ? (text, picture, ..) It is possible to extract your listview content and format the result, but is this what you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawing cache is only as big as the viewport.  You'll only ever save what's on screen this way.